# $a^2-b^2=bc$ and $b^2-c^2=ac \Rightarrow a^2-c^2=ab$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Some weeks ago our math teacher asked the following question and gave us a week to solve it:

> If $a^2-b^2=bc$ and  $b^2-c^2=ac ,$ Prove $a^2-c^2=ab$, Where $a,b,c$ are non-zero real numbers.

This seemed really easy at the first, but when i tried to prove it i just failed every time. After a week, I only came up with this idea: Assume our case is true. $a^2-c^2=ab\Rightarrow a^2-b^2+b^2-c^2=ab\Rightarrow bc+ac=ab\Rightarrow\frac{1}{abc}(bc+ac)=\frac{1}{abc}(ab) \Rightarrow$
 $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{c}$. Now if we Prove this, our case will be proved as well.

  In my opinion this seemed like a really nice question so i wanted to share it with everyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To begin with, note that by adding the two given equations together, we can immediately conclude that $$a^2-c^2=(a+b)c.\tag{$\star$}$$

Now, multiply both sides of $(\star)$ by $a-b,$ giving us $$(a^2-c^2)(a-b)=(a^2-b^2)c\\a^3-a^2b-ac^2+bc^2=bc^2\\a^3-a^2b-ac^2=0\\a(a^2-ab-c^2)=0,$$ so since $a\ne 0,$ we can conclude that $a^2-ab-c^2=0,$ so that $a^2-c^2=ab,$ as desired.

Comment: You are right. I will say state that in the question.

Comment: +1, Thanks for the nice answer, it was very similar to the answer our teacher almost gave us. I will accept your answer if no nicer answers were given in a while :P

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: There isn't a need to check that $a-b \neq 0$. You can always multiply a true statement by any constant, and still have the resultant statement true. If you multiplied by 0, then the resultant statement will be true, even if the initial statement is false.

Comment: @Calvin: That's an excellent point. In hindsight, I'm not sure why I worried about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can chug through this by eliminating the $a$ variable and following your nose. 
$$b(b + c) = b^2 + bc = a^2 = {(b^2 - c^2)^2 \over c^2}$$
We can assume that $b \neq -c$, since if $b = -c$ the first equation implies $a = 0$, contradicting that $a,b,c$ are all nonzero. So we can divide by $b+c$ to get
$$b = {(b^2 - c^2)(b-c) \over c^2}$$
Multiplying by $c^2$ and expanding this becomes
$$bc^2 = b^3 - c^2b - cb^2 + c^3 \tag 1$$
You want to show $a^2 - c^2 = ab$. Substituting your first equation into $a^2$ and the second into $ab$ this is equivalent to showing
$$b^2 + bc - c^2= {b^2 - c^2 \over c}b$$
Multiplying by $c$ this is equivalent to
$$b^2c + bc^2 - c^3= b^3 - c^2b \tag 2$$
Rearranging terms, $(2)$ is the same as $(1)$.